# how to know when cdh 5.10 will come out

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-cdh, impala, cloudera-manager, cloudera-director

Does anyone know how to find a Cloudera road map for releases for all services and components for CDH?  I can see here https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/impala_incompatible_changes.html#incompatible_changes_28x a lot of stuff about Impala w.r.t. to CDH 5.10 and I can see in the repository https://repository.cloudera.com/cloudera/cloudera-repos/com/cloudera/cdh/cdh-root/5.10.0-SNAPSHOT/ that CDH 5.10 had additions on Nov 28.  How can I find when CDH 5.10 will be released or when it is planned to be released, the next minor version the same thing, etc. But they don't talk about it in the official notes here http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/release-notes/topics/rn_consolidated_pcm.html.  I'm hoping there is some insight into this somewhere on the net?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloudera releases a new CDH 5.X.0 release approximately every 3 months. By taking a look at the dates of previous releases you can have a fair idea on when to expect the next one.

According to http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/parcels/, CDH 5.9.0 became available on 21 of October. So I would expect the 5.10 in the end of January, 2017.

Comment: Exactly right - it is out today Jan 31st (http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2017/01/cloudera-enterprise-5-10-is-now-available/)